# Molding a complex object to another complex topology object?

Tags: modeling, modifiers

I'm studying Blender and using it along with Adobe Fuse CC, and I managed to create my own anime body, and wanted to import on fuse. With some help on the forums they told me I needed the exact same topology, and that most 3d programs would be able to morph their base mesh to mine.
I tried it using shrinkwrap, knowing there was no way it would work, since vertex numbers and all that stuff is different, and ofc it didn't.

Is there any semi-automated way to adapt the base mesh to my own mesh?
I dont have my mesh here, but I do have a manuel bastioni generated character, same issue.
Original Mesh:

[image: Shrinkwrap result]

Shrinkwrap result
[image]

Comment: Welcome to Blender.Se. Shrinkwrap modifier doesn't need the same number of vertex/faces to work, and it's often used to retopology the meshes. Obiuvsly it works best when the two object are similar. But as you said, if you need the exact same topolgy, you shoul try to adapt the base mesh to yours. Could you show some picture of what are you trying to do in Blender? Where are you exacctly stuck?

Comment: uploaded some images, that is fuse basemesh and the result after shrinkwrap

Comment: Can you add description to your images telling what is what? Can you show the mesh you are shrinkwrapping to?

Comment: [link](http://imgur.com/a/exeB6) This is what I have now, it`s a manuel bastioni mesh, mine has some different mesh around the waist but the result i'm getting is very similar on both.

Comment: Can you add an image with the shrinkwrap settings... or upload a file to [Blend Exchange](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/)

Comment: I think I did this right: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=3655" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/3655/)

Comment: The two meshes are very different and they don't  correctly overlap. Shrinkwrap tries to project the surface, but the target is too distant. You can try adjust them, but it would be very long and difficoult. I don't think there's any plugin that would help you in this task. I would suggest to rebuild your model upon the give mesh without altering the topology.

Comment: Actually I have sculpted what I wanted into the base mesh already, I was just asking after seeing WrapX software.